# .Set is not taking the last character of the input string in a WebEdit

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to enter a string or numeric value in a webedit. Below is the code I am using:

```
Browser("name:=Online Shopping.*").Page("title:=Online Shopping.*").WebEdit("name:=q").Set "books"
```

OR

```
Browser("name:=Online Shopping.*").Page("title:=Online Shopping.*").WebEdit("class:=_2zrpKA").Set "10"
```

But it is taking only "book" or "1". It is not taking the last character.Though the maxlength of `webedit` is 548224.

Comment: Does this happen on all sites? Which browser and version of QTP/UFT are you using?

Comment: Try using the `.Type` method of the `WebEdit` rather than `.Set` and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Motti,Thanks for supporting.I tried in another sites as asked by you,and its working perfectly fine.Thanks for the idea.
Hi Dave,Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Rupali, by any chance do you override the set method with `RegisterUserFunc`?

Comment: I had face slightly similar issue because of corp policy we were not allowed clear cache and it was auto completing some fields, but **`.SendKeys`** method helped me that time. Have you tried that?